# how to add neutral sentiment to the trained dataset ? using sklearn and nltk

Tags: python, logistic-regression, sentiment-analysis

I have a python script that works on sentiment analysis in order to predict the sentiment of the text.

- positive
- negative
- neutral

The problem is that the trained and tested dataset  includes only 2 class of classification positive & negative.

but when i run this model on real data i detect neutral classification that is not existing in my trained data and this cause a problem because the system predict  it as positive or negative.

I am using the **logisticRegression** model with **tfidf** , **cross validation** , **bigram**  and **GridSearchCV**.

## code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer,TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn import model_selection

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix,accuracy_score

cross_val = KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=42)
# create pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('bow', CountVectorizer(strip_accents='ascii',
                            stop_words=['english'], 
                            lowercase=True)),  
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),  
    ('classifier', LogisticRegression(C=15.075475376884423,penalty="l2")), 
])

# this is where we define the values for GridSearchCV to iterate over
parameters = {'bow__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2)],
              'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),
                
             }



# tuned_parameters = [{'C': np.linspace(.0001, 1000, 200) , 'penalty': [ "l1", "l2"]}]
# clf = GridSearchCV(regression, tuned_parameters, cv=cross_val, scoring= 'roc_auc')
clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameters, cv=cross_val, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1, scoring= 'roc_auc')
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

results = model_selection.cross_val_score(clf, x_train,y_train,cv=cross_val)
```

Comment: If there are more than two classes, you'll need multilabel classifier. See this sklearn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) on the same.

Comment: the problem is that the trained dataset that i have includes only 2 classification positive and negative.

so i want to have a train dataset with **neutral sentiment** also.
LogisticRegression model is a multilabel  classifier

Comment: The problem statement is unclear. First, you say the train and test data has labels for positive and negative labels. Then you say the real data has neutral labels. Are you suggesting, the train and test data are separate from the so called "real data"? if this is the case, then why are you using the train data? I hope you understand the concept of population and sample? The train and test data must be from the population, else the subsequent modelling will make no sense,

Comment: @vilisSO yes its seperated from the real data ...isn't the purpose of trained and test dataset is to create a model that you can use it on other dataset related to the same category like twitter  ??

Comment: i have a feeling that you've misunderstood the machine learning game. In this game, the population remains the same. This population is split into train, test and validation sets. In majority cases, its only split into train & test sets. The model is initially shown or "trained" on the train set. It's then exposed to the test set to check its accuracy or sensitivity. In some cases, its can further be exposed to the validation set too.

Comment: so each AI project that includes NLP  processing it can be used on one dataset only ? and every dataset that i need let say to make a prediction must be splited into train and test ??

this will not take for ever in order to make train  then test to have at the end a perdition ?

Comment: my initial hunch was correct. Suggest to read the text , [Applied Predictive Modelling](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-6849-3) authored by Max Kuhn published by Springer. It'll answer all your Qs

Comment: reading comments above giving me acknowledges, thanks..